# Can you use Next.js and Node.js and Express.js altogether? Like replacing React in the MERN stack with Next.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, next.js, next.js13

I used to use Node and Express with React for all of my side projects, but ever since Next.js 13 came out, I am attracted by the **Server Side Rendering feature** and the simplicity of that framework.

So I'm wondering if Next.js is compatible with the traditional way of development, if I just swap out React with Next.js since they both seem very similar with jsx/tsx for my next project? Will it work theoretically so I still get the functionality of Node and Express with Server Side Rendering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can Do Simply By Deleting API Folder in In next.js 13

And Write API And Back-End in Node And Express.js
And Write Front-End in Next JS